# Having problems using MySql in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: asp.net, mysql, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to develop an ASP.NET project in Visual Studio 2010 which will be having access to MySQL database located on the local server.

I have installed MySQL 5.1 and the NET Connector for MySQL using the Web Platform Installer. And I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate (version 10 - SP1) with .NET 4.5 installed. I've added references to MySQL.Data, MySQL.Web and MySQL.Data.Entity in my project.

I'm facing the following issues.

When trying to link MySQL objects in my ASPX pages, the MySQL library is not accessible. Meaning when I try typing .. MySQL..  The intellisense does not pick it up. It seems the MySQL library has not been added at all to the project, whereas I can see it in my references. Because of this I cannot create MySQL objects in ASPX pages.

I wanted to have some of my common code put in a Class (e.g. ComCode.vb). I've been told that I must put that ComCode.vb file inside a folder App_Code. I don't see App_Code folder by default so I manually create a folder. (I don't see App_Code folder in Add>Add ASP.NET Folder menu as well). The folder has a special icon, im guessing the project picked it up. When I put my ComCode.vb class file in it, the intellisense does not work on it. It treats it like an unformatted raw text file. I searched on net and found that I must change Build Action of the class file from Content to Compile. That works. But creates new problems for me.

I shifted my MySQL code from ASPX file to the Class file. Now for some strange reasons Visual Studio recognizes the MySQL objects. Now it remembers that my project has references to MySQL libraries. But it doesn't recognize the objects when theyre in ASPX code. I even tried importing namespace but since it doesn't recognize libraries hence the importing doesn't work as well.

Anyhow now the MySQL works in the class file. I can create a new instance of class in ASPX page and call my function to connect and open the MySQL database. But now there's a new problem. When the webpage is running on the IIS Express 7.5 server, it gives me the following error:

Type 'MySqlConnection' is not defined.

This error is given on this line:  Public objConnection As MySqlConnection

The code in my ComCode.vb:

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Imports MySql.Data

Public Class farazdb
    Public objConnection As MySqlConnection


    Public Function Connect() As Boolean

        Dim conStr As String
        Dim config As NameValueCollection = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("appSettings")
        conStr = config("ODBCConnection")

        Try
            objConnection = New MySqlConnection(conStr)
            objConnection.Open()
        Catch ex As MySqlException
            Return ex.Message.ToString()
        End Try

        Return True

    End Function
End Class
```

I've added the following line in Web.config:

```
<appSettings >
  <add key="ODBCConnection" value="Server=localhost; Database=mydb; uid=xxxx; password=xxxx;"/>
</appSettings>
```

I really don't know what's happening here. What to do? Any help is appreciated.

Regards

Faraz

Comment: Well I've discovered it on my own. It seems Visual Studio has two different project types, Web Application and Website. All this time I was working on Web Application, which was causing the above mentioned issues. When I created a new Website project in VS2010, it was all resolved.